# Taking These Tables and Associating Their Appropriate Teams Together

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I was recently assisted with getting the scores from a yahoo NHL page that would print out the teams and their aforementioned scores in a respective manner. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = urlopen("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/scoreboard?d=2013-01-19")

content = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

def yahooscores():
    results = {}

    for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='scores'):
        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            scores = []
            name = None
            for cell in row.find_all('td', class_='yspscores'):
                link = cell.find('a')
                if link:
                    name = link.text
                elif cell.text.isdigit():
                    scores.append(cell.text)
            if name is not None:
                results[name] = scores

    for name, scores in results.items():
        print ('%s: %s' % (name, ', '.join(scores)) + '.')

yahooscores()
```

Now, first of all: I am associating this stuff in a function because I am going to have to change the url constantly to get all the values of every day of the January month.

The issue here is that while I can print the scores and team text fine, I am trying to accomplish this:

```
Ottawa: 1, 1, 2.
Winnipeg: 1, 0, 0.

Pittsburgh: 2, 0, 1
Philadelphia: 0, 1, 0.
```

See, my code doesn't do that. I was in the process of trying to get that to happen, but what is complicating the process is that the tables are all under the same class of "scores" and seemingly, I can't find anything different amongst them.

In a nutshell, associate teams correctly with each other and have a space in-between for organization.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you do get so we can see what's wrong? Is it that you can't separate out the team matchups?

Comment: When I run this, I get exactly those four lines you want, together with a bunch of others (for the other teams), in arbitrary order. So presumably what you want has something to do with putting `Ottawa` and `Winnipeg` together, separately from `Pittsburgh` and `Philadelphia`, with a line between them… but I have no idea what that "something" could be. (I can imagine why you might want Pittsburgh and Philly together, but Ottawa and Winnipeg are in different conferences, different provinces, different everything…)

Comment: @abarnert Did you visit the page in a browser? Presumably the goal is to show the teams for each game together with a newline in between. =)

Comment: @rakslice: Yes, I visited it in a browser. I see "No games scheduled" that way. The only place any teams appear are in the standings on the right side which have the teams organized by division.

Comment: @rakslice: Ah, I see. If I use the "canonical URL" I find on that page, it displays properly in any browser. Otherwise, it displays with minimal formatting in Firefox, while it displays with the formatting but not the actual scores in Chrome… Looking at it in Firefox, I can see what the OP probably wants.

Comment: @abarnert Odd. I copy-pasted the URL from the code, and I get a page without any standings on the right; and I get the same thing in IE 10, FF 23 and Chrome 28.

Comment: @rakslice: I get the scores without standings and with screwy formatting in FF23 and FF14, the standings without scores and with what formatting that looks like it matches the front page in Chrome 29 and Safari 6. I wonder if it's trying to give me Android/iOS pages for Chrome and Safari? Anyway, it obviously isn't relevant to the OP's problem…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is, you're putting the results for each team into a `dict`, but there's no order in a `dict` and so you loose track of which scores came from which table on the page (i.e. which game).

To get around this, you could just print the results directly instead of storing them, and add an extra newline in the outer for loop:

```
def yahooscores():
    results = {}

    for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='scores'):

        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            scores = []
            name = None
            for cell in row.find_all('td', class_='yspscores'):
                link = cell.find('a')
                if link:
                    name = link.text
                elif cell.text.isdigit():
                    scores.append(cell.text)
            if name is not None:
                print ('%s: %s' % (name, ', '.join(scores)) + '.')

        print ""

yahooscores()
```

Or, if you want to store the scores and show them later, you can store the teams for each game as well and use them to group the results:

```
def yahooscores():
    results = {}

    games = []

    for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='scores'):
        teams = []

        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            scores = []
            name = None
            for cell in row.find_all('td', class_='yspscores'):
                link = cell.find('a')
                if link:
                    name = link.text
                elif cell.text.isdigit():
                    scores.append(cell.text)
            if name is not None:
                results[name] = scores
                teams.append(name)

        games.append(teams)

    for teams in games:
        for name in teams:
            scores = results[name]
            print ('%s: %s' % (name, ', '.join(scores)) + '.')
        print ""

yahooscores()
```

Comment: Oh great! Yes, the first solution worked best for what I was going for. My appreciations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're treating the table as a flat list of teams, rather than as a list of scores, each of which has two teams in it.

The clean way to fix that is to change the way you parse the page so you loop over the games, then, for each game, store something like a pair of names-and-scores.

---

But there's also a quick&dirty solution: If you kept the teams in order, you could just pair them up after the fact. A `dict` has no inherent order, but an `OrderedDict` preserves the order of insertion. So, just change `results = {}` to `results = collections.OrderedDict`.

(Although if the only thing you ever do with this dict is iterate its `items()`, I'm not sure why you want a dictionary at all. Just do `results = []`, replace `results[name] = scores` with `results.append((name, scores))`, and then iterate over `results` instead of `results.items()`.)

And now, if you want to print them out in pairs… well, you can make an iterator over pairs from any iterable very easily. For example:

```
def pairs(iterable):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*2)

for (name1, score1), (name2, score2) in pairs(results.items()):
    print ('%s: %s' % (n1, ', '.join(s1)) + '.')
    print ('%s: %s' % (n2, ', '.join(s2)) + '.')
    print
```

Or, if you can't figure out what that means, something hacky like this works fine too:

```
pair_done = False
for name, scores in results.items():
    print ('%s: %s' % (name, ', '.join(scores)) + '.')
    if pair_done:
        print
    pair_done = not pair_done
```

… or:

```
for i, (name, scores) in enumerate(results.items()):
    print ('%s: %s' % (name, ', '.join(scores)) + '.')
    if i % 2:
        print
```